# Chrome Extension: Network Panel - Need to disable default question mark triggering help behavior

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension that adds a custom devtools panel. My panel has some text boxes that allow user input, but any time I type a question mark, it opens Chrome help instead of tying the '?' character. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

UPDATE:
I should have mentioned that I'm using React in my extension and that I was using React's synthetic events.

Comment: Do you type it inside a text input or where? Do you have a keydown listener? If so, try specifying `true` in its third parameter. If it doesn't help, consider reporting on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Inside of a text input. I tried the capture option, and it still doesn't stop the help menu from opening.

Comment: Thank you. Are you seeing the same behavior?

Comment: https://crbug.com/923338

Comment: FYI, this turned out to be due to how I was using React and not a problem with Chrome.

Comment: It's still a bug in Chrome. Typing a character without modifier in a text input should not invoke the settings regardless of what you're doing in React or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be unrelated to Chrome and due to a React JS nuance.

I was trying to call event.stopPropagation() on a React synthetic event which doesn't actually stop propagation to non-react registered event handlers such as the one that opens the help dialog.

The fix was to register a keydown event to the native DOM element and calling stopPropagation on the native event. This properly stoped the help menu from opening in response to typing in my input.

e.g.

```
<input 
  ref={input => input.addEventListener(event => event.stopPropagation())}
  onChange={this.myOnChangeHandler}
  />
```